# OLEObject Height and Width are not consistent

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently attaching PDF files and images to my excel sheet as OLE Objects, and trying to control the size of them. (I want the icons to appear along a grid)

The problem is that even though each OLEObject should meet the following specifications, they are sometimes different sizes. Some pdfs have greater lengths, or widths then image files.

How do I make sure they are consistent?

```
Public Sub OLEObjectNamesReturn()

Dim Count As Integer
Dim Space As Integer
Count = 23
Space = 0

For Each oleObj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    Select Case oleObj.Name
    Case "CheckBox21"
    Case "CheckBox22"
    Case "CommandButton21"
    Case "CommandButton22"
    Case Else
        Dim ObjectName As String
        ObjectName = oleObj.Name
        Set oCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P" & Count)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ObjectName)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ObjectName).Height = 30
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ObjectName).Width = 30
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ObjectName).Top = oCell.Top + 7 + Space
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(ObjectName).Left = oCell.Left + 7
        Count = Count + 1
        Space = Space + 15
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: happy/unhappy with the answer? How can we help further? Please consider starting to accept answers, it will increase the community's motivation to answer more questions from you - Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default shapes have their **aspect ratio** (relation W/H) **locked** ... so in fact both your `.Height` and `.Width` settings will **change both** dimensions (unless they are square from start). If you want perfect squares no matter what is the original W/H ratio of your shapes, unlock the aspect ratio.

Suggestion:

```
Sub Test()
Dim OleObj As OLEObject

    Set OleObj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1)     ' embedded PDF A4 ... not icon
    OleObj.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    OleObj.Height = 30
    OleObj.Width = 30

End Sub
```

Tested wit a PDF originally A4 size ... one doesn't have to like the final look ;-)

If you want to maintain the aspect ratio but still want to fit your OLEObject into a 30x30 grid, you need to apply one single setting to the larger dimension, e.g.

```
' ....

If OleObj.Width > OleObj.Height Then
    OleObj.Width = 30
Else
    OleObj.Height = 30
End If

' ....
```

Then - to horizontally center the object you'd add `(30 - OLEObj.Width)/2` to `oCell.Left` etc etc ...

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about the LockAspectRatio. How did you come across this information? I'm working more and more with OLEObjects and images inside of excel and would like to know more.

Comment: @JohnFayt Graphics objects in a lot of languages behave like this ... and I had a similar challenge some years back when I had to bring OLE objects into a cell grid in Excel ... glad I could help.