# How to choose manually where to insert a value/picture

Tags: vba, excel

What I am looking for is a way in a VBA macro, to have a setting, so where my cell is activated (wherever in the sheet), there is where the macro will insert a specific value or picture.

Is it any way in doing this?

I just know how to specify a range in the macro to where the picture should be inserted, but I would like it to be inserted where I manually have chosen via the mouse. My VBA code:

```
Sub Importera_bilder()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Kundinformation")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Partner_information")
    Set ws = Sheets("Kalkyl")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Start")


    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Projektunderlag").Activate
    FolderPath = ws2.Range("B21").Value
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = FolderPath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = counter + 1
                  'Sheets("Object").Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
                  'Sheets("Projektunderlag").Range("M" & counter).ColumnWidth = 10
                'Sheets("Projektunderlag").Range("M" & counter).RowHeight = 13
                'Sheets("Projektunderlag").Range("M" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("Projektunderlag").Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 270
            .Height = 230
        End With
         ActiveSheet.Range("M269").Select
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("M269").Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("M269").Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: do you want to specify a location while this code is running (i.e. should it stop somewhere to ask you "Where do you want to drop that pic") or is the location already selected before `Importera_bilder()` is called?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `ActiveCell` property.

For instance if I wanted to place the number 900 in the cell I have selected my VBA would be:

```
Sub Insert900()
    ActiveCell.Value = 900
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Could you perhaps help me with understanding where in this code i then should insert the activecell value?

Please look at the code above.

Comment: Give me a better explanation of what you are currently doing and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

in `Sub Importera_bilder()` include/change

```
....
Dim PicNail as Range        ' this is where we nail the pic to
Set PicNail = Selection     ' current cell cusrsor position
....
Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter, PicNail)
```

and the Insert function becomes ...

```
Function insert(PicPath, counter, NailTo As Range)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)

        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 270
            .Height = 230                  ' don't do both!
        End With
        .Left = NailTo.Left
        .Top = NailTo.Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

***Note:***

When you have AspectRatio locked, there's no use to change both width and height because either one will be automatically adjusted when you set the other one (that's the sense of aspect ratio)

When you want to fit your image into a 270W x 230H box, you need to set the larger dimension (whichever it is) and aspect ratio is retained.

further reading:

[VBA Excel 2010 - Embedding Pictures and Resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073463/vba-excel-2010-embedding-pictures-and-resizing/22075626#22075626)

[OLEObject Height and Width are not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750196/oleobject-height-and-width-are-not-consistent/28751656#28751656)

Also be aware that the `Picture.Insert` method in Excel 2010 behaves different than before ... it is insertin g a LINKED object, so you may want to include assignments to `LinkToFile` and `SaveWithDocument` or change code to `ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(...)`

Comment: Hi everyone, i have another question regarding this issue. Everything has been solved very nicely, but i was wondering if you know any way on how i can set in which order the images should be imported (arranged by newest date etc). Is it any way of doing this?

Comment: can you please accept the best answer to the original question (if you can accept any of the answers provided) and raise a new question for what you asked in the comment