# Insert OLEObject in specific cell with specific width and height

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert files when this function is called.

I want the input file to be shown with a specific width, height, and have the icon of the file.

I also want to have the input be in a specific cell.

Is there a better way to define what cell I want the input to be in? I want the input to be in cell 'I5' but I am not sure how to go out doing this with the top and left parameters in OLEObjects.Add.

```
Sub FileToLink()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strShortName As String
    Dim f As OLEObject
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFileName("All Documents (*.*), *.*")

    If strFileName = "False" Then
        Exit Sub ' user cancelled
    End If

    strShortName = InputBox("What do you want to call this link?", "Short Text", strFileName)

    Set f = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                        Filename:=strFileName, _
                                        Link:=False, _
                                        DisplayIcon:=False, _
                                        IconFileName:=strFileName, _
                                        IconIndex:=0, _
                                        IconLabel:=strShortName, _
                                        Top:=Range("I5").Top, _
                                        Left:=Range("I5").Left, _
                                        Width:=10, _
                                        Height:=10)

End Sub
```

Thanks to an answer I changed the Top and Left to make the input in the correct cell, however I am still unsure on how to change the width and height.I Keep getting an input box that is longer than it is tall.

Comment: `Top:=Range("I5").Top` Etc

Comment: Nice! Thank you @TimWilliams! I am still stuck on width and height though. No matter what I input it just gives me the same box that is wider than its height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750196/oleobject-height-and-width-are-not-consistent