# Resizing OLEobject custom icon

Tags: vba, excel

I have code to insert pdf invoice copies in customer's account statement. The code is working fine. Just the custom icon size is not as per the defined 15x51 (HxW). Please suggest how the code can resize the icon file to fit in this 15x51 box (the size of cells in column M as in below picture)? I am using a 16x16 icon file.

Here is the current result.

[image]

```
    Sub Insert_PDF_File()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim cell As Range

' loop each cell in column A
        For Each cell In Range("A10:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
' make sure the cell is NOT empty before doing any work
             If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

' create and insert a new OleObject based on the path
                Dim ol As OLEObject
' ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & cell & ".pdf" will make the filename
                Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                                    Filename:="C:\Invoices\Renamed" & "\" & cell & ".pdf", _
                                                    Link:=False, _
                                                    DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                                    IconFileName:="C:\Users\pvishwas\Documents\WORK\Macros\PDF.ico", _
                                                    IconIndex:=0, _
                                                    Height:=15, Width:=51, IconLabel:="Open")
' align the OleObject with Column D - (0 rows, 3 columns to the right from column A)
                With ol
                    .Top = cell.Offset(0, 12).Top
                    .Left = cell.Offset(0, 12).Left

                End With
            End If
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: What about using `.Width` and `.Height` to resize the `ol`?

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28751656/2727437

Comment: Thanks, @Marcucciboy2. This post has helped. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it completed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Unfortunately, ``.Width`` and ``.Height`` did not work for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

According to me, it's due to icon size.

Please check below the code I created. It takes given size for object.

```
Sub AddPDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FilePath As String
Dim x As OLEObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
FilePath = "D:\certificate-of-earnings.pdf"

ws.Range("A1").Select
ws.OLEObjects.Add Filename:=FilePath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Height:=15, Width:=51, IconLabel:="PDF"

End Sub
```

[image]